# MySQL stored procedure If exists

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a stored procedure in MySQL, and having trouble using IF EXISTS

My SQL is;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`##`@`%` PROCEDURE `myTestProceedure`(IN _id INT)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cms.variables WHERE tmplvarid = 5 and id = _id) THEN
    BEGIN
    UPDATE cms.variables SET value = now() WHERE id = _id and tmplvarid = 5;
    END;
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cms.variables (`tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (5, _id, now());
    END;
    END IF;
END
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do in this procedure is IF the row already exists in the DB, update it, otherwise insert it.

However despite whatever result `SELECT * FROM cms.variables WHERE tmplvarid = 5 and id = _id` gives, it just inserts into the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in if exits just do as `select 1 from` instead of `select *`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`##`@`%` PROCEDURE `myTestProceedure`(IN _id INT)
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM cms.variables WHERE tmplvarid = 5 and id = _id)>0 THEN
    BEGIN
    UPDATE cms.variables SET value = now() WHERE id = _id and tmplvarid = 5;
    END;
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cms.variables (`tmplvarid`, `contentid`, `value`) VALUES (5, _id, now());
    END;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: or just `select 1 from` ? but you are right `count(*)` should also do the trick since the subquery should not return more than one row. BTW +1

Comment: I've changed it to what you've both suggested, however that still keeps inserting despite data already having been inserted.

Comment: that means you dont have any record for tmplvarid = 5 and id = _id in your table. try to run SELECT count(*) FROM cms.variables WHERE tmplvarid = 5 and id = _id; and see the result

Comment: I ran the procedure three times, it created three rows in that table with tmplvarid = 5 and id = 1 (the id passed to the proc).

Comment: please run SELECT count(*) FROM cms.variables WHERE tmplvarid = 5 and id = _id;  where replace _id with your value and tell me the result

Comment: Ahh, just figured it. Wrong column name! The column name should be called contentid not id! Thanks for your help thought. It will come in handy for further development.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, you probably don't want to do `SELECT 1 FROM` because if your conditions aren't satisfied you will return the _Empty Set_. If you're doing an "if this condition then exit early" then ` IF (_Empty Set_ != requiredValue)` will return `FALSE` instead of `IF (0 != requiredValue)` which will return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me running MariaDB 15.1.
It just kept evaluating the IF condition as true and trying to insert the record even if it already existed.

This is what I ended up using:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ghost`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_updateTable`(IN `_id` mediumint,IN `_arg2` varchar(100))
BEGIN
    #Routine body goes here...
    DECLARE exist DECIMAL DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO exist FROM `database`.`tbl_example` WHERE (`tbl_example`.`ID` = _id AND `tbl_example`.`arg2` = _arg2);
    IF exist < 1 THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO `database`.`tbl_example` VALUES (_id,_arg2);
        END;
    END IF;
END
```

Hope this helps someone else with this problem